# set angular velocity not working in andengine

Tags: android, rotation, andengine, physics, velocity

I am trying to do flappy bird like game in andengine. I achieved everything and everything worked out but the rotation is not working. setangularvelocity is not working

my code is as follows

onscenetouch I am giving linear velocity as follows

```
body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(2, 2)); 
 float omegaFactor = (float) -1.0;
 body.setAngularVelocity((float) ( (Math.PI) * omegaFactor) );
```

please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you check your body? May be the rotation is "off" ?

Comment: oh finally I got it. The physicsconnector has a parameter to boolean updaterotation. It was in false in my game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physics connector has a boolean paramter which states the update of body rotation.

Unfortunately it was false in my game. I changed it to true and it worked.

```
physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(levelObject, body, true, false));
```

to

```
physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(levelObject, body, true, true));
```